# Aligning text in a nav bar in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

Ok so obviously I'm doing something wrong. Basically I'm trying to create a vertical navigation bar at the top of my page, to the right of a picture.

It should look like this:

> > Home Resume Contact Me

Somehow it keeps ending up like this:

> > Home Resume
> >
> > Contact Me

Can you guys take a look and help me out? This is my first website. Thanks!

Here's my code:

HTML

```css
html {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
#menu {
  width: 550px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: Courier, Serif;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#menu ul {
  height: auto;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #224466;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>Tyler Tilton</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">Bio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Personal Website\Images\Profile Pic.png" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: move the menu into the body rather than head

Comment: Do you mean a horizontal navigation? Vertical means it'd be going up and down, horizontal is left and right. Also, your page content should be in `<body>`, not `<head>`.

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/dgzv1dja/) what you wnat???

Comment: Also, fix width. Because of you limiting the width they are ending up like that. Just did width:100% and they aligned the way you wanted. Here's a fiddle using @Lal example: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/dgzv1dja/1/

Comment: No @Luis i think the Op wants the image to be 20% width and the rest,ie 80% width for the menu div..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy. The issue lies mostly in your `#menu` class. Your width is too small, you're text is too big, you have unnecessary margins and floats added. Remove all of that or adjust it and your list will align horizontally:

```
#menu {
  /*width: 550px;*/ //too small for text size
  height: 35px;
  /*font-size: 55px;*/ //to big for width size
  font-family: Courier, Serif;
  text-align: center;
  /*float: right;*/ //not necessary, at least in your demo, pushing text off screen
  /*margin-right: 300px;*/ //not necessary, at least in your demo
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cph66u7j/1/)

Comment: he said vertical but the `Home Resume Contact Me` example was clearly horizontal

Comment: Yeah sorry I totally meant horizontal! Thanks for the help! This worked!

Comment: Yeah I'm new to this website trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the font-size in **`#menu`**.
 Try reducing the font-size to 40px in #menu. It should bring them in one line.

Hope it helps!